# Vertical Centering of Title Text with Background Image (1 or 2 lines)

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/hP7y4/22/)

So I have a set of divs that include a title and a list of links. I would like the title to be vertically aligned with a background image bullet. It looks fine with 1 line of text but a title that wraps because of length will get pushed down and look funny.

If there are 2 lines of text I would like the text and the background image to be vertically aligned within the header box so they are in line with the other set of headings.

[image]

```
<div class="calloutCollection tiled">
    <div class="linksCallout Main">
        <div class="title"> <a href="#">
                Heading List 1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="links"> <a href="#">Child Bullet Link 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="linksCallout Main">
        <div class="title"> <a href="#">
                Heading-List Wrapped Because of Word Count</a>
        </div>
        <div class="links"> <a href="#">Child Bullet Link 1</a>
 <a href="#">Child Bullet Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="linksCallout Main">
        <div class="title"> <a href="#">
                Heading List 3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="links"> <a href="#">Child Bullet Link 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="linksCallout Main">
        <div class="title"> <a href="#">
                Heading List 4</a>
        </div>
        <div class="links"> <a href="#">Child Bullet Link 1</a>
 <a href="#">Child Bullet Link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the `padding-top` property from CSS for `.title` and add `line-height: 48px;` which is equal to the `height` so that it is vertically center aligned.

And for `.title a`, add this CSS :

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

**CSS :**

```
.calloutCollection.tiled .callout .title a, .calloutCollection.tiled .linksCallout .title a {
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/227117/images/bg_footer02.gif) no-repeat 6px 45%;
    padding-left: 21px;
    display: inline-block;  /* So that content */
    vertical-align: middle; /* floats in middle */
    background-position: 6px 40%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333 !important;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-decoration: none!important;
}
.calloutCollection.tiled .callout .title, .calloutCollection.tiled .linksCallout .title {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 48px; /* To center align text vertically */
    background: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/227117/images/bg_sec_top_product_01.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
    font-size: 75%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/niks999/84Gh6/1/)

Comment: Nice. Thanks Nikhil. I am mostly a c# developer so I am still working on this UI stuff.